# Mixture gas in modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I use OpenModelica and I have some model gas mixture

```
package ExhaustGas
import Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common;
  extends Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa(mediumName = "ExhaustGas", data = {Common.SingleGasesData.O2, Common.SingleGasesData.CO2, Common.SingleGasesData.H2O, Common.SingleGasesData.N2, Common.SingleGasesData.Ar, Common.SingleGasesData.SO2}, fluidConstants = {Common.FluidData.O2, Common.FluidData.CO2, Common.FluidData.H2O, Common.FluidData.N2, Common.FluidData.Ar, Common.FluidData.SO2}, substanceNames = {"Oxygen", "Carbondioxide", "Water", "Nitrogen", "Argon", "Sulfurdioxide"}, reference_X = {0.1383, 0.032, 0.0688, 1 - 0.1383 - 0.032 - 0.0688 - 0.0000000001 - 0.0000000001, 0.0000000001, 0.0000000001});
end ExhaustGas;
```

I run the code:

```
algorithm
for i in 1:6 loop
      etaX[i] := ExhaustGas.fluidConstants[i].criticalTemperature;
end for;
```

and I get

```
{154.58, 154.58, 154.58, 154.58, 154.58, 154.58}
```

That is, only oxygen values are written to the array.

The same loop is used in the function *Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa.dynamicViscosity*.
Can this function be considered to work correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of OpenModelica are you using? The example from the answer of Hans Olsson works fine with OpenModelica v1.14.0-dev-26633-gd9901afc5b.

Is `{154.58, 304.12, 647.096, 126.2, 150.86, 430.8}` your expected answer?

Comment: I appologise for delay. I am using v1.13.2. Yes, {154.58, 304.12, 647.096, 126.2, 150.86, 430.8} is expected answer.

Answer (score 3):

I could not see any similar issue in Dymola (used Dymola 2018 for no obvious reason), so that seems like an issue in OpenModelica.

To get the example to run I used:

```
model ExhaustGas
  import Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common;
  package P=Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa (
    mediumName="ExhaustGas",
    data={Common.SingleGasesData.O2,Common.SingleGasesData.CO2,Common.SingleGasesData.H2O,
        Common.SingleGasesData.N2,Common.SingleGasesData.Ar,Common.SingleGasesData.SO2},
    fluidConstants={Common.FluidData.O2,Common.FluidData.CO2,Common.FluidData.H2O,
        Common.FluidData.N2,Common.FluidData.Ar,Common.FluidData.SO2},
    substanceNames={"Oxygen","Carbondioxide","Water","Nitrogen","Argon","Sulfurdioxide"},
    reference_X={0.1383,0.032,0.0688,1 - 0.1383 - 0.032 - 0.0688 - 0.0000000001 -
        0.0000000001,0.0000000001,0.0000000001});

  Real etaX[6];
algorithm 
  for i in 1:6 loop
      etaX[i] =  P.fluidConstants[i].criticalTemperature;
  end for;
end ExhaustGas;
```

Since a model inheriting from a package isn't legal. I noticed two warnings for the normalBoilingPoint being out of range.

*Changed*: I changed it to use algorithm instead of equation, it doesn't make a difference in Dymola, and I don't see any reason why it should matter.

Comment: But if I change "equation" to "algorithm" it works incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, I missed that you used "algorithm" - but that just narrows down the bug.

Comment: Package inheriting from a package works exactly the same. I do not really understand what your say about the normalBoilingPoint.